# how to raw_input the size of a file in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

i want to create a searching script in python  that search  .exe file in linux from a given path by its size,extension  and to list .

Comment: how is your code wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `import *` is a no no. Always import the exact thing(s) you want to use. Second, a combination of the modules `glob`, `fnmatch` and `os.path.getsize()` would get the job done.